# Files folder changes permissions randomly

Tags: files

It seems that the sites/default/files folder of a project looses the permissions from time to time - and I have no idea how it comes. Suddenly error logs appear stating that the public files folder does not have the correct permissions which is true: it changed from 775 to 755 so that it is not possible any more to upload files.

Does any one has an idea what can cause this issue?

Comment: what is the `owner/group` set to?

Comment: If php runs as www-data then you should set the owner/group to www-data. It will be able to write to the folder then.

Comment: Ok... the owner is another user as www-data, the group is www-data. I wondered if there are any security issues when setting the owner of the files folder to www-data. So you say I can do that? But what can lead to the permission change in Drupal?